# How to use a regular expression to search for two patterns surrounding another pattern

Tags: regex, perl

Not sure if this is even possible. I need to parse a text file in perl to extract lines beginning with an IP address that is thousands of lines long. However the caveat is the pattern I'm searching for may occur numerious times in the text file but I only want to extract one instance of it... Sample of the text file below:

```
Random network information. 
cn_DomainIntity : ps_Domain
more text
10.162.55.123 RadioBearerSetup
some text
some more text
cs_Domain
random text
10.162.55.136 RadioBearerSetupComplete
network stats
10.162.55.122 RadioBearerSetup
text
ps_Domain
text
10.162.66.125 RadioBearerSetupComplete
 ... 
 ...
```

Basicly what I would like to do is extract the lines of the text file that starts with RadioBearerSetup and ends with RadioBearerSetupComplete but contains ps_Domain somewhere between.

I have been using the flip flop operator and while it kind of does what I want, it extracts all instances of the file which start with RadioBearerSetup and end with RadioBearerSetupComplete
my code below:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 


my $file= "datafile.txt";
open (my $FH, "<", $file) or die "Cannot open <$file>: $!";

while ($FH) {
    print if /\bRadioBearerSetup\b/ .. /\bRadioBearerSetupComplete\b/;
}
close($FH);
```

Comment: If you read the whole file into a string, you could use a tempered greedy token: [`(?s)\bRadioBearerSetup\b(?:(?!RadioBearerSetup(?:Complete)?).)*\bps_Domain\b(?:(?!RadioBearerSetup(?:Complete)?).)*\bRadioBearerSetupComplete\b`](https://regex101.com/r/rO1zQ0/1). However, I guess there are other better solutions here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
my @data;
my $found = 0;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/\bRadioBearerSetup\b/ .. /\bRadioBearerSetupComplete\b/) {
        $found = 1 if /\bps_Domain\b/;
        push @data, $_;
    } else {
        last if $found;
        @data = ();
    }
}
print Dumper\@data;

__DATA__
Random network information. 
cn_DomainIntity : ps_Domain
more text
10.162.55.123 RadioBearerSetup
some text
some more text
cs_Domain
random text
10.162.55.136 RadioBearerSetupComplete
network stats
10.162.55.122 RadioBearerSetup
text
ps_Domain
text
10.162.66.125 RadioBearerSetupComplete
 ... 
 ...
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          '10.162.55.122 RadioBearerSetup',
          'text',
          'ps_Domain',
          'text',
          '10.162.66.125 RadioBearerSetupComplete'
        ];
```

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I want it to do!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably approach your problem like this:

- use a regular expression to select the 'chunks' of data out of your file (e.g. like your flipflop)
- grep the results to filter the desired stuff.

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/;

my @blobs = <> =~ m/([\d\.]+ RadioBearerSetup.*?RadioBearerSetupComplete)/mgs;
print grep { m/ps_Domain/ } @blobs;
```

Result:

```
10.162.55.122 RadioBearerSetup
text
ps_Domain
text
10.162.66.125 RadioBearerSetupComplete
```

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth this is my take on it

**Code**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @data;

my $domain;

my $textFound = 0;

my $href = {};

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    # found the first domain skipping that one
    if ( /cn_DomainIntity\s+:\s+\bps_Domain\b/ ){
        next;
    }
    # start grapping data
    if (/\bRadioBearerSetup\b/) {
        $textFound = 1;
        push @data, $_;
    }
    # end grapping data
    elsif (/\bRadioBearerSetupComplete\b/) {
        push @data, $_;

        #push into hash ref
        push @{$href->{$domain}},@data;

        # reset the flags
        $textFound = 0;
        $domain = "";

        # reset data
        @data = ();
    }
    # grab the domain name
    elsif (/\b([a-z]{2}_Domain)\b/) {
        $domain = $1;

        push @data, $domain;
    }
    # misc text
    elsif (1 == $textFound){
        push @data, $_;
    }
}

print Dumper $href;

__DATA__
Random network information. 
cn_DomainIntity : ps_Domain
more text
10.162.55.123 RadioBearerSetup
some text
some more text
cs_Domain
random text
10.162.55.136 RadioBearerSetupComplete
network stats
10.162.55.122 RadioBearerSetup
text
ps_Domain
text
10.162.66.125 RadioBearerSetupComplete
```

**Output** shows a hash separated by domain

```
$VAR1 = {
      'ps_Domain' => [
                       '10.162.55.122 RadioBearerSetup',
                       'text',
                       'ps_Domain',
                       'text',
                       '10.162.66.125 RadioBearerSetupComplete'
                     ],
      'cs_Domain' => [
                       '10.162.55.123 RadioBearerSetup',
                       'some text',
                       'some more text',
                       'cs_Domain',
                       'random text',
                       '10.162.55.136 RadioBearerSetupComplete'
                     ]
    };
```